# What is the replacement of libibverbs/librdmacm for Windows?

Tags: rdma, mellanox

We have our application running on Linux and using RMDA (Infiniband) interface for communication between two modules. Now we like to support our application on Windows and hence looking for IB Verbs replacement.

We tried installing Mellanox Drivers but we are unable to locate headers and libraries to get our code to compile on Windows. Simple *infiniband/verbs.h* is also not found.

We also found that RDMA on windows is supported via Windows NDK, but it seems to be a very low level.
We are looking for some middle layer API set to port our existing Linux based code to Windows.

It will be much appreciated if someone can show us what path we should follow.

Kind regards

Comment: Further to my analysis; I am able to port my Linux RDMA (Infiniband) code to Windows using winOFED [link](https://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/Windows/) with 3.2 version. But it seems to be too old and does not support the latest HW like Mellanox Connect 5x. Hence i started trying with WinOF-2 driver [link](https://www.mellanox.com/products/adapter-software/ethernet/windows/winof-2). But what i see is the SDK format (headers and libraries) are not same what i got from winOFED 3.2. Please help me in understanding what is the difference? Does i am using wrong SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on finding Verbs in Windows. Switched to NetworkDirect.

https://docs.mellanox.com/display/winof2v250/Network+Direct+Interface

https://github.com/microsoft/NetworkDirect

The code above provides a similar API as to Verbs.

Comment: Another example using NetworkDirect: https://github.com/microsoft/hermes

Comment: Tianyi Cai, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)